# Google App Script - sheet.getCharts() and Trend Charts

Tags: google-apps-script

Since Google spreadsheets do not support dynamic ranges (ex. A:A), I need to be able to update the range of a trend chart using App Script.  Unfortunately the getCharts() method for the Sheet object doesn't return entries for trend charts.  Can trend charts be accessed via a script?  I have verified that the following code works fine for other chart types.

```
function expandCharts() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();

  for (var i in charts) {
    var chart = charts[i];
    var ranges = chart.getRanges();
    var builder = chart.modify();
    for (var j in ranges) {
      var range = ranges[j];

      builder.removeRange(range);
      var newRange = expandRange(range, 5);
      builder.addRange(newRange);
    }

            builder.setOption('title', 'Last updated ' + new Date().toString());
    sheet.updateChart(builder.build());
  }
}

function expandRange(range) {
  var s = range.getSheet()
  var startCol = range.getColumn();
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();
  var startRow = 1;  
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();

  range = s.getRange(1, startCol, lastRow, numCols);  
  return range;
}
```

Comment: Google Spreadsheets support the ranges like Sheet1!E:E or Sheet1!10:10. To check it, create an new spreadsheet, select entire column or row by clicking on the column/row header, select the Data->Named and protected ranges menu item and click to the "+ Add new range" item. You will see that the Google Spreadsheet will use entire row or columns as a range.

Comment: two problems with that ...(1) inserting a chart does not allow the use of named range.  (2) when you create a named range for a column eg L:L it takes on the current extent of the spreadsheet and converts it to say L1:L123 and does not extend it when rows are added

Comment: @DavidF. In fact the named ranges do not support ranges like `L:L` but it does not mean that Google Spreadsheets do not support such ranges. It means that named ranges do not support this feature. People read this topic and they could make a conclusion that the Google Spreadsheet does not support "dynamic ranges" and this is not correct. Another example, create a new sheet, in the created sheet add the `=SUM(A:A)` formula to the cell `B1`, type to any cell in the column `A` numbers. the the `B1` cell value will be automatically changed.

Comment: @megabyte1024. I agree, named ranges do not support the feature and nor does charts. I  recognised the pain inherent in the q of dealing with charts defined over ranges that extend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see a way to do it myself. The Charts service does not allow you to create a TREND chart either. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_charts

Edit: "not all chart types are supported" https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_charts_charttype

Comment: I was afraid of this and appreciate you taking the time to confirm my suspicions.  I was cautiously optimistic that someone would have a work around.  My dirty solution will be to create a static range and update the data within that range.  Kinda silly because users won't be able to see all of the history but oh well.  Thanks again!